# How to insert date & int in to sqlite databse

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

Im using SQlite in my iPhone app.
to insert date value i used code like this:

```
    NSDate *time;
    [dict setObject:time forKey:@"time"];

    if(sqlite3_bind_text(insertStmt, 1, [time NSDate], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK) 
   {

        return NO;
    }


    int type;       
     NSNumber *type = [NSNumber numberWithInt:type];
            [dict setValue:type forKey:@"type"];
    if(sqlite3_bind_text(insertStmt, 2, [type int], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK) 
     {

        return NO;
    }
```

it shows an warning: **incomplete pointer type passing 'id' to perameter of type const char**

what to do ? 
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to convert the int value into NSNumber..

```
sqlite3_bind_int(insertStmt,2,type);
```

Comment: Thnk u very much.. Then how about date type

Answer (score 1):

change like this for inserting int value in database

```
 sqlite3_bind_int(updStmt, 4, [type int]);
```